# Sending mail using PHP with Prestashop doesn't work

Tags: php, ubuntu, prestashop

I get an issue using `mail(),` it doesn't work...

Error message : `Sending failed using mail() as PHP's default mail() function returned boolean FALSE.`

I'm using Prestashop but it doesn't work.

Comment: check for server mail config

Comment: Ok, but where can I check that?

Comment: You can use PHPMailer for sending mail. It will work easy for you. [Link1](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) [Link2](http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/)

Comment: What is your hosting provider?

Comment: Ok, but what am I supposed to edit in `php.ini`? SoYouStart by OVH and I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: contact your host provider to check mail config if you have shared hosting